# Data Comparison in Python Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, series

That are 2 Data Series that i wish to compare based on a third.

data_SKU1:

```
SKU     Weight1     
1234    20
1235    30
111     40
101     23
```

data_SKU2:

```
SKU     Weight2
1234    22
1235    35
111     47
101     87
```

flag_Data:

```
SKU
1234     True
1235     False
111      True
101      False
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Basically based on the values in the flag_Data Serie, i need to divide the value of Weight1 by Weight2 or vice-versa.

For intance:

```
j = flag_Data(dados_SKU1, dados_SKU1) #this generates the third series
if(j[1234]==True):
  generated_serie = data_SKU1['Weight1'][1234] / dados_SKU2['Weight2'][1234]
else:
  generated_serie = data_SKU2['Weight2'][1234] / data_SKU1['Weight1'][1234]
```

But it should be done for all SKU's in the series, not only SKU 1234. Could you guys help to figure it out how?

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***
**`merge`**

```
df = df1.merge(df2)

    SKU  Weight1  Weight2   FLAG
0  1234       20       22   True
1  1235       30       35  False
2   111       40       47   True
3   101       23       87  False
```

***Option 1***
**`np.where`**

```
df['division'] = np.where(df['FLAG'], df['Weight1']/df['Weight2'], df['Weight2']/df['Weight1'])
```

***Option 2***
**`loc`** with **`fillna`**

```
df.loc[df['FLAG'], 'division'] = df.Weight1 / df.Weight2
df['division'] = df.division.fillna(df.Weight2/df.Weight1)
```

***Option 3***
**`mask`** with **`fillna`**

```
df['division'] = (df.Weight1 / df.Weight2.mask(~df.FLAG)).fillna(df.Weight2/df.Weight1)
```

All result in:

```
    SKU  Weight1  Weight2   FLAG  division
0  1234       20       22   True  0.909091
1  1235       30       35  False  1.166667
2   111       40       47   True  0.851064
3   101       23       87  False  3.782609
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where for this:

```
result = np.where(flag_Data,
                  data_SKU1['Weight1']/data_SKU2['Weight2'],
                  data_SKU2['Weight2']/data_SKU1['Weight1'])
```